Generate link to page or tt_content element selected with TCA group field
I've got a TYPO3 plugin which allows selecting a page or a content element via a TCA group form field (with <allowed>pages,tt_content</allowed>).
Now I want to link to that selected page/content element in my fluid template.
The values in the field are either page_23 or tt_content_42.
What is the most easy way to link to either page or content element from a fluid template?
I cannot use <f:link.page> because it does not accept page_23 values in the uid parameter, nor does it accept the tt_content_42 value in there. <f:link.typolink> has same problem as far as I see.

The easiest way is probably to migrate the field to a link field - if it really is “only” a link in terms of content.
You may be able to extract and link the pages using f:replace. But for tt_content you need a pageId (or a LinkHandler that searches/finds it)

You can implement your own ViewHelper. Here's the basic outline. Create a "ViewHelpers" folder in Extname/Classes/ and add a file called CustomLinkViewHelper.php
In the ViewHelper, you can use regex to match "tt_content_42" and check if it refers to tt_content or a page. Based on this, you can create your custom queries.
Here's the docs for a custom viewhelper. You don't need to register anything in your Extension. Just create the path and you are good to go!
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/DevelopCustomViewhelper.html#fluid-custom-viewhelper-implementation

there are various ways, but the easiest is with a Viewhelper.
The group field type is polymorphic meaning as you previously stated it can contain pages and tt_content references. This also means you should treat it as an array of references.
First, create a Viewhelper to hold the logic.
Create a file under your extension at Classes/ViewHelpers/HasManyPolymorphicViewHelper.php
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourExtension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;


class HasManyPolymorphicViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    /**
     * This ViewHelper does not need child nodes to be processed
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $escapeChildren = false;

    /**
     * This ViewHelper will not escape the output
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $escapeOutput = false;

    /**
     * Initialize arguments for the ViewHelper
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        $this->registerArgument('references', 'string', 'Polymorphic references', true);
    }

    /**
     * The main function that will be called to execute the ViewHelper logic
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function render(): array
    {
        $references = $this->arguments['references'];
        
        $connectionPool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
      
        $rows = [];

        # Map references to table => ids representation to fetch all records
        foreach ($this->groupGroupReferences('pages,tt_content', $references) as $table => $ids) {
            $rows[$table] = [];

            $queryBuilder = $connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
            $result = $queryBuilder
                ->select('t.*')
                ->from($table, 't')
                ->where(
                  $queryBuilder->expr()->in('t.uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($ids, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY))
                )
                ->executeQuery();

            while ($row = $result->fetchAssociative()) {
                $rows[$table][] = $row;
            }
        }
        
        return $rows;
    }
    
    private function groupGroupReferences(string $allowedList, string $referencesList): array
    {
        if (empty($allowedList) || empty($referencesList)) return [];
        $references = explode(',', $referencesList);
        $allowed = explode(',', $allowedList);

        # Non table containing list
        if (count($allowed) == 1) {
            $groupedRelations = [
                $allowed[0] => array_map(function($id) use ($allowed) {
                    if (str_contains($id, '_')) {
                        $parts = explode('_', $id);
                        $id = array_pop($parts);
                        $table = implode('_', $parts);

                        if ($table !== $allowed[0]) {
                            throw new \Exception('Unallowed reference table detected');
                        }
                    }

                    return intval($id);
                }, $references)
            ];
        } else {
            $groupedRelations = [];

            foreach ($references as $reference) {
                $parts = explode('_', $reference);
                $id = array_pop($parts);
                $table = implode('_', $parts);

                if (!array_key_exists($table, $groupedRelations)) {
                    $groupedRelations[$table] = [];
                }

                $groupedRelations[$table][] = intval($id);
            }
        }

        return $groupedRelations;
    }
}

Secondly, use the Viewhelper in your Fluid template, just pass the references into the viewhelper instead of the hard coded example:
{namespace my=Vendor\YourExtension\ViewHelpers}

<h2>Related Records</h2>

<!-- Use the HasManyPolymorphicViewHelper to get records based on references -->
<f:for each="{my:hasManyPolymorphic(references: 'pages_1,tt_content_2')}" as="records" key="table">
    <h3>Table: {table}</h3>
    
    <f:for each="{records}" as="record">
      <f:if condition="{table} == 'tt_content'">
        <f:then>
          <f:link.page pageUid="{record.pid}" section="c{record.uid}">Link to page</f:link.page>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
          <f:link.page pageUid="{record.uid}">Link to page</f:link.page>
        </f:else>
      </f:if>
    </f:for>
</f:for>

Above code was borrowed from Pagedoctor extension:
Github
